# Angular 5 Karma Test Fails with Imports

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I recently migrated a project from Angular 2 to 5 and now any test cases that have to do with compiling views are breaking. Previous tests that were working are not anymore.

To break down the issue, I created a very simple test to try and find what is happening.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [Component],
        imports: [MatCardModule] //Breaks if any import is here (e.g. SharedModule)
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents(); //Breaks once this is run
}));
it('should display something',
    expect("").toContain("");
});
```

No error comes up if the import is there, it just does not run any more test cases. If the import is not there, it tells me to verify that Mat-Card is a part of the module.

Here is relevant part of package.json (recently updated Karma):

```
"jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"karma": "^2.0.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
"karma-systemjs": "^0.16.0"
```

**UPDATE**

After some investigation, I now believe it is a config issue with Karma.

I was able to get around the MatCardModule issue by adding

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

to the TestBed. Though when adding providers, it will work with basic classes that do not require imports, but any that are more complex (e.g. ObservableMedia) will not work even if the appropriate imports are given. No error will come up either, none of the tests will even run.

Comment: Remove async from the it statement. You are also defining Component in declarations, remove that too.

Comment: @Steverob2k Same issue. Nothing runs if import is there. The basic test runs if I remove the import but I need the import for other scenarios. Also if I remove the declaration, when I try to do TestBed.createComponent(Component), I get 

"Failed: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive BalanceComponent."

Comment: You either have to add more declarations as to what the component is using. Or If the component you are testing is in a module, import that too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after about a week of poking around, I figured out a solution that worked for me.

I had originally used *Angular Seed* as a starter project but this was well over a year ago. When upgrading to Angular 5, I used a guide online instead of upgrading the Angular Seed project. Though it worked, not all my test cases were running.

I spent the time to upgrade the project files to the latest Angular Seed and all of the test cases started running after importing all the additional packages to `karma.config.js` (with some errors).

**Sidenote:**

The issue can also be due to not properly importing additional packages to Karma. Follow [this](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Add-external-dependency) guide for properly adding external dependencies.

If there are custom elements in the component you may need to also add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to the TestBed.